# SSL issues with WordPress site

Tags: jquery, login, ssl

So, I have a WordPress site that has SSL certificate installed. What I need is to disable SSL on some pages (to make a video ad script to work).

But, the problem I am having is, If an user logs in to site once and opens a non-ssl page, the user is shown as not logged in, also some jquery functionalities are not working on non-ssl page.

I've tried searching online but couldn't find a perfect solution.

Note: I ca't disable SSL completely, as SSL is very important on other pages.

Anyone know some kind of solution for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to figure out how to make the " video ad script" work instead of hacking your way around the problem?

Comment: I have to call an external resource from the company who provides ad but unfortunately they do not provide a link with https . I worked with ad server company regarding this but they didn't provide any solution. This is why I decided to use non-ssl on pages where we have videos.

Comment: That is going to cause security warnings

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the resource without http or https?

Another words add the external source like this:

```
    wp_register_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

As you can see I am calling the jQuery resource without adding http or https.